# Creating API Authentication using PHP Oauth class

Tags: php, oauth, api-authorization

I am trying to setup API authentication for APIs that I have created using PHP. My website, (Client) has been created using React. I have been researching and I cannot find anything that explains what I need to know. One of the main resources I am using is the PHP documentation:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

The things I am struggling with is the generating of the tokens, what information do I use in the creation of tokens? How do I setup my APIs to be classed as a `protected resource`?

From the understanding that I have about `oauth`, The client will send a request to the server for a request token. Once it has the request token, in the callback, it will request an `access token` using the `request token`. The `access token` will then be used to request access to the API. Does that sound right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if these are your API's you are protecting i don't know why you would go down this route, OAuth is usually for validating against a third party.

Comment: @tim oh I see. So what way would you recommend I use to protect against unauthorized calls?

Answer (score -1):

Oauth is pretty complex to implement, and is mostly used in situations where 3rd parties need to authenticate you users in their own code, or where there are complex authentication requirements.

Your case seems to be pretty simple, have you considered just using session/cookie based authentication, or using tokens generated on the server side?

Comment: Is there a specific PHP API that I need to use to generate the tokens or can I develop my own method? Do the tokens need to be stored in session variables or cookies?

Comment: You may find a pretty good tutorial on API authentication with JWT here: https://codeofaninja.com/rest-api-authentication-example-php-jwt-tutorial/